# SequenceFile Input format not recognized in Oozie workflow.xml?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, oozie

I have a MR program which runs perfectly on a bunch of SequenceFile's and output is as expected. 
When I try to achieve the same via an Oozie WorkFlow for some reason the InputFormat class property is not recognized and I feel the input is considered as default TextInputFormat only.

Here is how the mapper is declared. SequenceFile key is LongWritable and value is Text.

```
public static class FeederCounterMapper extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable>{

    // setup map function for stripping the feeder for a zone from the input
    public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException{

        final int count = 1;            

        // convert input rec to string          
        String inRec = value.toString();

        System.out.println("Feeder:" + inRec);

        // strip out the feeder from record
        String feeder = inRec.substring(3, 7);          

        // write the key+value as map output
        context.write(new Text(feeder), new IntWritable(count));
    }
}
```

The workflow layout for my application is as below

```
 /{$namenode}/workflow.xml
 /{$namenode}/lib/FeederCounterDriver.jar
```

The below is my workflow.xml. The $namenode, $jobtracker, $outputdir, $inputdir are defined in the job.properties file.

```
<map-reduce>
    <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
    <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
    <prepare>
    <delete path="${nameNode}/${outputDir}"/>
    </prepare>
  <configuration>
    <property>
        <name>mapred.reducer.new-api</name>
        <value>true</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>mapred.mapper.new-api</name>
        <value>true</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>mapreduce.job.queue.name</name>
        <value>${queueName}</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>mapred.input.dir</name>
        <value>/flume/events/sincal*</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>mapred.output.dir</name>
        <value>${outputDir}</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>mapred.input.format.class</name>
        <value>org.apache.hadoop.mapred.SequenceFileInputFormat</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>mapred.output.format.class</name>
        <value>org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextOutputFormat</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>mapred.input.key.class</name>
        <value>org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>mapred.input.value.class</name>
        <value>org.apache.hadoop.io.Text</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>mapred.output.key.class</name>
        <value>org.apache.hadoop.io.Text</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>mapred.output.value.class</name>
        <value>org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>mapreduce.map.class</name>
        <value>org.poc.hadoop121.gissincal.FeederCounterDriver$FeederCounterMapper</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>mapreduce.reduce.class</name>
        <value>org.poc.hadoop121.gissincal.FeederCounterDriver$FeederCounterReducer</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>mapreduce.map.tasks</name>
        <value>1</value>
    </property>                
</configuration>
</map-reduce>
```

A snippet of the stout(first 2 lines) when I run the MR job is

```
 Feeder:00107371PA1700TEET67576     LKHS  5666LH 2.....           
 Feeder:00107231PA1300TXDS  8731TX 1FSHS  8731FH 1.....
```

A snippet of the output(first 3 lines) when I run using Ooozie work flow is

```
 Feeder:SEQ!org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritableorg.apache.hadoop.io.Text�������b'b��X�...
 Feeder:��00105271PA1000FSHS  2255FH 1TXDS  2255TX 1.....
 Feeder:��00103171PA1800LKHS  3192LH 2LKHS  2335LH 1.....
```

With the above output from the Oozie workflow I highly doubt the input format SequenceFileInputFormat mentioned in the workflow.xml is even considered, else I feel this is overridden.

Any inputs towards this would help. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Find the job.xml created for this mapreduce job in job tracker and see what is the input format class being set there. This will confirm whether it is a problem with input format or not.

Answer (score 0):

I had a really similar problem and I got oozie to use the proper input format by setting my property like this

```
<property>
    <name>mapreduce.inputformat.class</name>
    <value>org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.SequenceFileInputFormat</value>
</property>
```

So one dot to remove from the property name (check for your version) and the class to change too.

Comment: I run Hadoop 1.2.1 and the solution which you had given is for Hadoop 2.x ? Am I right ? Thank you.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, this is for 1.2.x as well.